# Remove Chinese Traditional from Microsoft Translate

Tags: jquery, html, translation

I am looking to remove the Chinese Traditional option from my [Site](http://mycustomdevelopment.com/translate/). I am using [Microsoft Translate widget](http://www.microsofttranslator.com/widget/) and cannot find the correct ISO code. Here is the current code that removes all other languages.

```
/* <![CDATA[ */ setTimeout(function() { var s = document.createElement("script"); s.type = "text/javascript"; s.charset = "UTF-8"; s.src = ((location && location.href && location.href.indexOf('https') == 0) ? "https://ssl.microsofttranslator.com" : "http://www.microsofttranslator.com" ) + "/ajax/v2/widget.aspx?mode=manual&from=en&hidelanguages=ch,mww,zh-hant,zh-hans,zh-tw,zh-cn,zh-hk,zh-mo,zh-sg,zh-my,zh-rTW,zh-rCN,ar,de,it,id,ja,bg,ko,ca,lv,ur,zh,uk,fa,hi,el,da,he,cs,zh-CN,zh-TW,AF,AX,AL,DZ,AS,AD,AO,AI,AQ,AG,AR,AM,AW,AU,AT,AZ,BS,BH,BD,BB,BY,BE,BZ,BJ,BM,BT,BO,BQ,BA,BW,BV,BR,IO,BN,BG,BF,BI,KH,CM,CA,CV,KY,CF,TD,CL,CN,CX,CC,CO,KM,CG,CD,CK,CR,CI,HR,CU,CW,CY,CZ,DK,DJ,DM,DO,EC,EG,SV,GQ,ER,EE,ET,FK,FO,FJ,FI,GF,PF,TF,GA,GM,GE,DE,GH,GI,GR,GL,GD,GP,GU,GT,GG,GN,GW,GY,HT,HM,VA,HN,HK,HU,IS,IN,ID,IR,IQ,IE,IM,IL,IT,JM,JP,JE,JO,KZ,KE,KI,KP,KR,KW,KG,LA,LV,LB,LS,LR,LY,LI,LT,LU,MO,MK,MG,MW,MY,MV,ML,MT,MH,MQ,MR,MU,YT,MX,FM,MD,MC,MN,ME,MS,MA,MZ,MM,NA,NR,NP,NL,NC,NZ,NI,NE,NG,NU,NF,MP,NO,OM,PK,PW,PS,PA,PG,PY,PE,PH,PN,PL,PT,PR,QA,RE,RO,RU,RW,BL,SH,KN,LC,MF,PM,VC,WS,SM,ST,SA,RS,SC,SL,SG,SX,SK,SI,SB,SO,ZA,GS,SS,ES,LK,SD,SR,SJ,SZ,SE,CH,SY,TW,TJ,TZ,TH,TL,TG,TK,TO,TT,TN,TR,TM,TC,TV,UG,UA,AE,GB,US,UM,UY,UZ,VU,VE,VN,VG,VI,WF,EH,YE,ZM,ZW,zh-CHS,zh_rTW,zh-rHK,TW,HK,CN,zh-zho,zh-chi,zh_HANT,zh_TW"; var p = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.documentElement; p.insertBefore(s, p.firstChild); }, 0); /* ]]> */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer when i posted it to Facebook.

> zh-cht